# Grails external config file path

Tags: grails, config, configuration-files

I'am about to set up a external config file. So I'm using the grails plugin

```
compile "org.grails.plugins:external-config:1.1.1"
```

I create the application.groovy that looks like this

```
grails.config.locations = [
    "/Users/username/application.properties"

]
```

And my application.config file is exactly in this place. By creating a normal file i have access to it and can read out of it.
In my file i have three key value pairs like

```
firstkey=first
secondkey=second
thirdkey=third
```

Still this keys does not get added to my config file.
In the class which is placed in the src directory i am able to call the config like this

```
Holders.config
//No result on calling one of the keys
Holders.config.thirdkey
```

Has anyone an idea what I have to do additional

Answer (score 0, accepted):

grails.config.locations takes spring [resource patterns](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/resources.html)

Try

```
grails.config.locations = [
        "file:///Users/username/application.properties"
    ]
```

If the file is in the home directory of the user under which the app is running. You can even use

```
grails.config.locations = [
            "~/application.properties"
        ]
```

The examples are already there in docs [here](https://github.com/sbglasius/external-config)

You can enable debug log level for logger `grails.plugin.externalconfig`. And it will log messages if any of your configured external config file is not found.

```
logger("grails.plugin.externalconfig", DEBUG, ["STDOUT"])
```